# I need send a file from server to browser (web client)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need send a file from server to browser (web client) c# (ASP.NET)
But while download file, the program continue execution.
I try to use tasks, threads, async methods...

```
//Create a WebRequest to get the file
FileWebRequest fileReq = (FileWebRequest)FileWebRequest.Create(this.CaminhoCompleto);

//Create a response for this request
FileWebResponse fileResp = (FileWebResponse)fileReq.GetResponse();

if (fileReq.ContentLength > 0)
fileResp.ContentLength = fileReq.ContentLength;

//Get the Stream returned from the response
stream = fileResp.GetResponseStream();


// prepare the response to the client. resp is the client Response
HttpResponse resp = HttpContext.Current.Response;

//ERRO!!!
teste(stream, resp, fileResp);

string nomeArq = fileResp.ResponseUri.Segments[(fileResp.ResponseUri.Segments.Length) - 1];

//Indicate the type of data being sent
resp.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

//Name the file 
resp.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + nomeArq + "\"");
resp.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileResp.ContentLength.ToString());

//await stream.CopyToAsync(resp.OutputStream);
```

Comment: The file is returned in the HttpResponse which is only sent when your controller is done executing... If the processing is not important to the response, you can start a new thread that won't block the sending of the response.

Comment: Why use `FileWebRequest` and not just normal `FileStream`?

Comment: I want to use this [code](http://codes.codedigest.com/CodeDigest/39-File-Download-in-ASP-Net-with-C-.aspx) async

Comment: Why does it need to be async ? The response will only be sent when ALL processing is complete (except if you do the processing on a different thread).

Comment: Because it is necessary for the user interface to continue running with the download. (ASP.NET)

Comment: @YitzhakStone I think you need to read more on web architecture... The UI is 100% completly disconnected from your business logic. It will not block while the download is occuring.

Comment: Bun, I tried to use threads. In the thread, the answer comes unavailable (as it is not possible to read / write).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's too old and I don't remember the resolution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use an Iframe to request the file from the server. You can create one using JavaScript and make its src the server endpoint. It will open a save dialog from the browser when the content is ready to be downloaded.